Parenthesized Adjective Indication
Does a parenthesized adjective indicate (i) optionality or (ii) unimportant additional information? For example:

"That intuition helps to aggregate (complex) data". -> means that: (i) the intuition helps to aggregate both complex data as well as normal data (data that can optionally be complex)? Or that: (ii) this data is always complex, but the information that data is complex is not very important for the context?

"He usually reacts to my statements by asking (series of) questions." -> means that: (i) he reacts by asking either questions or a series of questions? Or that: (ii) he reacts with series of questions but the information that it is a series of questions is not very relevant/important?



You should give the source of any quotes, unless these examples are things you made up yourself. That helps when answering the question.

I made up the statements.

Note that your second example uses series of, which is not an adjective. Does your question really focus only on adjectives? I encourage you to edit your question and/or its title to attain consistency.

Thank you. What part of speech/grammar does "series of" have?

I'd read "That intuition helps to aggregate (complex) data" as "That intuition helps to aggregate data, usually but not confined to complex data." And "He usually reacts to my statements by asking questions ... and that's usually strings of questions."

It's not quite cricket to create ambiguity and ask if it is quite clear.

Writers place a qualifying adjective inside parentheses  when making a generalization but their  assertion is most relevant,  or only relevant, to the subset called out by the adjective.

When a (motorized) vessel enters that section of the canal the captain must cut  engine speed to prevent wake.

The adjective  is placed in parentheses sometimes defensively, in anticipation of nitpicking objections, such as the one one might raise there, that not all vessels have engines, though most proceeding along a (shipping) canal would.
Or they will add an adjective or adverb in parentheses to indicate a specific detail or fact for the sake of accuracy, precision, or completeness but that  detail is not (directly) relevant to the point they're making.

When the mayor spoke before a (visibly angry) crowd of citizens gathered in front of the municipal office building a month ago, he promised to move negotiations along and  bring the trash haulers strike to an end. And yet trash is still piling up on the streets.

It is a form of shorthand, the convention sparing them having  to "spell things out" in a plodding manner.

This is not a universal stylistic standard and is understood contextually: It can be used to express the "optional" version:
"He usually reacts to my statements by asking (series of) questions." -> "He usually reacts to my statements by asking questions; often, a series of them."
or for clarity
"In French and biology lessons, he usually reacts to statements by asking long questions - especially of Mr Pierre (French)."
